# Get the correct position of visible DIV using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have following code, in which some div are hidden and only div with some class like "2020"will be visible

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.listCard').hide();
  $('.listCard.2020').show();
  console.log("last visible -->"+$(".listCard.2020:visible:last").index());
  console.log("First visible -->"+$(".listCard.2020:visible:first").index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm listCard 2018">2018</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2018">2018</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
</div>
```

But when I get the index of first and last div which is visible and have class '2020' it shows different then expected.

Expected result is first visible should be 0 and last should be 6.
I just need variable which shows position of the div, can we use any other method.

Demo with code
https://jsfiddle.net/5ak8hvq7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to know the position in relation to the other elements, you want to run index on the collection.

Can you try this and see if it helps ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.listCard').hide();
    $('.listCard.2020').show();

    let listItems = $('.listCard.2020').slice(1);
    console.log("First: " + $('.listCard.2020').index(listItems));
    listItems = $('.listCard.2020').slice(-1);
    console.log("Last: " + $('.listCard.2020').index(listItems));          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian Patterson's answer is correct. I made a few adjustment over it. Hope it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if($(".listCard").hasClass("2020")){
      $(".listCard.2020").show();
      let listItems = $('.listCard.2020').slice(0);
      console.log("First: " + $('.listCard.2020').index(listItems));
      listItems = $('.listCard.2020').slice(-1);
      console.log("Last: " + $('.listCard.2020').index(listItems));
   }         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the element that you are trying to find the index of to [`.index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index) if you want to find its position *relative* to that collection. Note this means you need to use `".listCard.2020:visible"` as the selector to get the collection of visible elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.listCard').hide();
  $('.listCard.2020').show();
  console.log("last visible -->" + $(".listCard.2020:visible").index($(".listCard.2020:visible:last")));
  console.log("First visible -->" + $(".listCard.2020:visible").index($(".listCard.2020:visible:first")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2018">2018</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2018">2018</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2019">2019</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
  <div class="col-sm listCard 2020">2020</div>
</div>
```